# Selecting placeholder's value as a selected value in asp.net mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, placeholder

I am using Telerik Dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC3.

I have take placeholder in it as `Select`.

After selecting value when i'll click on reset button, I want to set dropdownlist's selected value as a value of placeholder.

Want to do this in a jquery.

I tried many options like this:

```
  1.   $("#DropDown1").val($("DropDown1 option:first").val());

  2.   $("#DropDown1 option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');

  3.   $("#DropDown1").val("Select");

  4.   $("#DropDown1")[0].selectedIndex = 0;

  5.   $("#DropDown1").selectmenu("refresh");
```

But none of these are working.
My dropdownlist is in a .ascx view like:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Placeholder("Select").Name("DropDown1").BindTo(new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["DropDown1"], "Value", "Text", true))%>
```

I am fetching the list in a dropdownlist from ViewData and I have took Select as a placeholder

Want some suggestions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my question on my own:

I used this function:

```
function setValue() {
    var DropDownList = $("#DropDown1").data("tDropDownList");
    DropDownList.select(0);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but using standard HTML only this will make the selected item be "Select" on a reset:

```
<form>
    <select>
        <option value="option1" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="reset" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sir, am using the telerik dropdownlist for a getting result on the basis of selected item.and using this dropdownlist in a .aspx view. am adding my dropdown in question so that u can understand it

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used this control. It also seems like Telerik have updated it: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/combobox#configuration-placeholder. The link is to the ComboBox. I Couldn't find placeholder for the dropdown.